# Triggering job in Jenkins pipeline with choice and boolean parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to my Job1 pipeline to tigger Job2, where Job2 expects "string", "choice" and "boolean" parameters. So on Job1, I have

```
build job: "Job2",
      parameters[
        string(name: "STRING_PARAM", value: "someStrig"),
        choice(name: "CHOICE_PARAM", value: "someChoice"),
        booleanParam(name: "BOOL_PARAM", value: true)
      ],
      wait: false
```

However, it doesn't like `choice`. I tried `choiceParam` and it didn't like that either. What's the correct syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `StringParameterValue`:

```
  build job: "Job2",
      parameters: [
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: "STRING_PARAM", value: "someStrig"],
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: "CHOICE_PARAM", value: "someChoice"],
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: "BOOL_PARAM", value: true],
        ],
      wait: false
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the purpose of changing the names and values of my first two parameters?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake ! Answer edited.